# Entity Framework. Detecting if an Entity is loading from the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to detect if an entity is being populated from the database by entity framework?

In the Setter of some properties I have logic that needs to be run if the property is being set by the UI, but not if it is being set by EF loading from the database.

There are a couple of reasons for this.

I am doing some force validation in the setters that depend on other properties that may have not yet been initialised when EF populates the properties.

I wish to preserve the values loaded from the database that would otherwise be force set by the logic.

Edit:
Back in the old days before EF, we had our own framework. All entities had a property, "Loaded", which the framework set to true once it had finished initialising the entity. It is this that I wish to do in EF.

Comment: Can't you use the id property of these entities?

Comment: That's exactly the reason why you shouldn't do validation in setters. Validation while reading from the database is bad practice (you should always be able to count on the database content as being valid) and a possible performance killer. You must validate an entity as a whole before it's saved, for example by making it implement `IValidatableObject`. In other words, you shouldn't need what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Entry()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.entry?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbContext_Entry__1___0_) method on the context to get information about a given entity. Use it to get the [state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state) of an entity. Check it against the states `Unchanged` and `Modified` to see if it is an entity from the database.

```
EntityState state = context.Entry(yourObject).State;
if (state == EntityState.Unchanged || state == EntityState.Modified) {
    // do something
}
```